# Do the paths intersects? If so where

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

There are two unidentified objects in the sky. The path of the first object is given by $r(t)=\langle t,-t,1-t\rangle $ and the second object's path is $s(t)= \langle t-3,2t,4t\rangle$

Do the paths intersect? If so where and do the objects collide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two objects with paths $r(t)$ and $s(t)$.

If you ask whether the two paths intersect at some point, then you just want to know if there are values $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $r(t_1) = s(t_2)$. That is
$$
t_1 = t_2 - 3\\
-t_1 = 2t_2 \\
1 - t_1 = 4t_2 
$$

Can you find a $t_1$ and $t_@$ such that this is true? If so, Ttat means that the two object will both pass the point, just not necessarily at the same time.

So want to figure out whether or not the objects collide. That is, you want to figure out whether or not there is one value of $t$ such that $r(t) = s(t)$. That is
$$
\langle t, -t, 1-t\rangle = \langle t - 3, 2t, 4t\rangle
$$

So you ask if this equation has any solution. If it does have a solution, then the two objects with be in the same location at that time, and so they collide.

Comment: How would you describe the paths?

Comment: @user95616: how would you?

Comment: Thomas I found how to describe the paths